# How to use one context menu in some places

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate like this:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SchemeContextMenu">
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataTemplate>
```

How can I use this template below?

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SchemeContextMenu}"/>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Do you define a datatemplate only for the ContextMenu? You can define the context menu as Resource and then recall in your textblock as ContextMenu={StaticResource NameOfTheResource}

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. With x:Shared="False"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a Context menu as Resource

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="myContextMenu">...</ContextMenu>
```

then recall it in you text block as

```
<TextBlock ContextMenu={StaticResource myContextMenu} />
```